# n2cms parent pages DroppableZone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2cms

I try to make the parent page showing part in all child page but I cannot be I try to using this code but its not working only for the start page\

```
@{ Html.DroppableZone(Content.Traverse.StartPage, "Recursive-Right").Render(); }
```

im using N2CMS dinamico edition

Answer (score 1):

Recursive zones are now supported in Dinamico as of v2.5.1. Try upgrading and see if that fixes your issue.

```
Install-Package N2CMS.Dinamico
```

or get the latest bits here: https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/releases